# How to print columnName=Value in new row by reading CSV file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a CSV file `Foo.csv` with the following data:

```
Name,Age,Education,Address
Alex,22,Computer Science, TX
Ron,24,Computer Science, AU
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
Name=Alex
Age=22
Education=Computer Science
Address=TX

Name=Ron
Age=24
Education=Computer Science
Address=AU
```

The CSV file can have many rows going forward. Any oneliner tool can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F' *, *' -v OFS='\n' -v ORS='\n\n' '
    NR==1{split($0,h); next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=h[i]"="$i}
1' file
Name=Alex
Age=22
Education=Computer Science
Address=TX

Name=Ron
Age=24
Education=Computer Science
Address=AU
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the space characters before `TX` and `AU` are typos:

```
$ awk -F',' 'FNR==1{split($0, a); next}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print a[i] "=" $i; print ""}' Foo.csv
Name=Alex
Age=22
Education=Computer Science
Address= TX

Name=Ron
Age=24
Education=Computer Science
Address= AU
```

This would print a newline after each block.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks @Freddy

Comment: If you use `-F' *, *'` that'll remove the extra blank after `=` in the Address field.

Comment: @EdMorton Your answer looks great, please undelete it.

Comment: @Freddy OK I undeleted it.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is always the same column order and always the first line, holding the columns:

```
<Foo.csv tail -n '+2' | awk -F',' '{print "Name="$1"\nAge="$2"\n"}'
```

Starts a pipe with content of Foo.csv. Skips first line (tail seems off by one, thus +2) and renders all others with comma as separator (-F',', first is $1, second $2) in blocks split by newline. Fill in the missing field(s). Mind the single quotes around awk's command block and the double quotes for static text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat print.sh 
#!/bin/sh

echo "Name=$1\nAge=$2\nEducation=$3\nAddress=$4\n"
$ cat Foo.csv | csv-exec -- ./print.sh %Name %Age %Education %Address
```

csv-exec is from https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools.